# creating a grails domain class from its class name

Tags: grails, reflection, groovy

I am trying to use the `Class.forName('com.mypack.MyDomain').newInstance()`
to create an instance of the grails domain from its qualified name.
But Its throwing a `ClassNotFoundException.` 
I assume this is because the `.forName('')` expects the class to be a java class instead of a groovy class?
How to make this work in grails, or is there another method to create the domain object from the class name in String format.

Thanks
Priyank

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another route to try would be to do:

```
GrailsDomainClass dc = grailsApplication.getDomainClass( 'com.mypack.MyDomain' )
def newDomainObject = dc.clazz.newInstance()
```

Comment: how do I pass the ID of the domain and get the particular domain object from the database table? Like otherwise I would do, User user = User.get(id);

Comment: Afaik, `dc.get( id )` should be what you need

Comment: Thanks.. for the help... its almost all done... the last issue is I get domain.dirtPropertNames.each{.. //how do I get the property value from the string value in the list? since domain.it obviously doent work..

Comment: Is there anyway to cast the `newDomainObject`?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
GrailsClass clazz =  grailsApplication.getArtefactByLogicalPropertyName(DomainClassArtefactHandler.TYPE, className)
clazz.clazz.newInstance()
```

Comment: So again I get an Object of type GrailsClass?

Comment: No, give it a try - that would be the object of the type of your domain class. The class name that you passed to getArtefactByLogicalPropertyName